# Handle only the dates of an array

Tags: php, arrays

How do I list only dates from an array.

**Use this code:**

```
do { 
   $integrantes[] = $row_rs['integrantes'];
} while ($row_rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($integrantes);
echo  '</pre>';
```

**result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2:2014-08-13,4:2014-08-13,6:2014-08-13,7:2014-08-13
    [1] => 3:2014-08-13,5:2014-08-13,6:2014-08-13
)
```

Comment: I'm guessing it involves: Splitting on `,`, a little `substr()` magic, and an inner loop-de-loop to do. Or maybe some fancy regex'n.

Comment: db normialisaton in the first place would me this s lot easier.

Comment: why are you using a `do while` instead of a `while`? it seems `$row_rs` will be undefined during the first iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
$integrantes = array(
    '2:2014-08-13,4:2014-08-13,6:2014-08-13,7:2014-08-13',
    '3:2014-08-13,5:2014-08-13,6:2014-08-13'
);

$result = array();
foreach($integrantes as $delimited) {
    $records = explode(',', $delimited);
    foreach ($records as $record) {
        list($id, $date) = explode(':', $record);
        $result[] = $date;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "2014-08-13"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "2014-08-13"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "2014-08-13"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "2014-08-13"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "2014-08-13"
  [5]=>
  string(10) "2014-08-13"
  [6]=>
  string(10) "2014-08-13"
}
```

Here is **[Codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/iZmZqp)** demo

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
while ($row_rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
    preg_match_all('/\d{4}\-\d{2}-\d{2}/', $row_rs['integrantes'], $matches);
    $integrantes = array_merge($integrantes, $matches[0]);
}
```

Comment: -1 for using [regex when unnecessary](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/113243/108554)

Comment: this is a simple job and regex will work fine. we are not dealing with heavy HTML parsing whatsoever, [see this other article](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/74635/what-can-should-be-done-with-regular-expressions/74640#74644)

Comment: I agree with @dragonjet, no reason to not use regex in this case. However, a note, I would use a while-loop instead of a do-while.

Comment: ah, I overlooked that. originally copied OP's loop. thanks I'll edit the answer to make it a while loop to handle zero-results